# Using a function and lapply for a date sequence in R

Tags: r, date, lapply

I am trying to not use a for loop and use a function and lapply to generate a sequence of dates separated by days and append it to data.
First, I tried

```
    x = data.frame(
        date = seq.Date(from = as.Date((q)[['d1']]),to = as.Date(q[['d2']]),by = "days"),
        m = (q)[['m']],
        stringsAsFactors = F
    )
    return(x)
}
y = list(
    d1 = as.Date(c("2012/01/31","2012/01/14")),
    d2 = as.Date(c("2012/01/31","2012/01/21")),
    m = c(100,75))
z <- do.call(rbind,lapply(y,fn))
```

but I get Error in `[[.default`(q, "d1") : subscript out of bounds and I tried to fix that using get()

Then I tried

```
    x = data.frame(
        date = seq.Date(from = as.Date(get(q)[['d1']]),to = as.Date(get(q[['d2']]),by = "days"),
        m = get(q)[['m']],
        stringsAsFactors = F
    )
    return(x)
}
y = list(
    d1 = as.Date(c("2012/01/31","2012/01/14")),
    d2 = as.Date(c("2012/01/31","2012/01/21")),
    m = c(100,75))
z <- do.call(rbind,lapply(y,fn))
```

I tried this but I get Error in get(q) : invalid first argument

Comment: Don't just randomly call unfamiliar functions; read their documentation. `get` is completely unsuitable here. Regarding your original code, you are iterating over the outer list items, not the inner ones. To solve your issue it might help to [transpose](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/transpose.html) the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `lapply` on a `list`, it applies the function to each column individually. Your `lapply(y, fn)` is equivalent to `list(fn(y[["d1"]]), fn(y[["d2"]]), fn(y[["q"]]))`, because those are the list items. Of course this doesn't work because your function is expecting a `list` with a single value for each of `d1`, `d2`, and `q` as input.

Making minimal changes, we can convert your list to a data frame and applying the function to rows:

```
dy = as.data.frame(y)
result = do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(dy), \(i) fn(dy[i, ])))
result
#         date   m
# 1 2012-01-31 100
# 2 2012-01-14  75
# 3 2012-01-15  75
# 4 2012-01-16  75
# 5 2012-01-17  75
# 6 2012-01-18  75
# 7 2012-01-19  75
# 8 2012-01-20  75
# 9 2012-01-21  75
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. not sure what you did here \(i) fn(dy[i, ] but I think I can figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: `\(i) fn(dy[i, ])` is shorthand for `function(i) fn(dy[i, ])`. My `lapply` goes over each row number, and `fn(dy[i, ])` is `fn()` on the `i`th row of `dy`.